# Hibernate Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to get Products by categoryId, categoryName and so I was writing in some custom queries but nothing seems to work. I am new to hibernate.

// this is my product class

```
    package springmvc.java.domain;        
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "product")
    public class Product {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "productId" , nullable = false)
        private Long productId;

        @Column(name = "productName", nullable = false)
        private String productName;

        @Column(name = "productCost", nullable = false)
        private double productCost;

        @Column(name = "productDescription")
        private String productDescription;

        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId", nullable = false)
        private Category category;

        public Long getProductId() {
            return productId;
        }

        public void setProductId(Long productId) {
            this.productId = productId;
        }

        public String getProductName() {
            return productName;
        }

        public void setProductName(String productName) {
            this.productName = productName;
        }

        public double getProductCost() {
            return productCost;
        }

        public void setProductCost(double productCost) {
            this.productCost = productCost;
        }

        public String getProductDescription() {
            return productDescription;
        }

        public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
            this.productDescription = productDescription;
        }

    }
```

// ********************************************************

//category class

```
    package springmvc.java.domain;
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "category")
    public class Category {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "categoryId", nullable = false)
        private Long categoryId;

        @Column(name = "categoryName", nullable = false)
        private String categoryName;

        @Column(name = "categoryDescription")
        private String categoryDescription;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private List<Product> products;

        public Long getCategoryId() {
            return categoryId;
        }

        public void setCategoryId(Long categoryId) {
            this.categoryId = categoryId;
        }

        public String getCategoryName() {
            return categoryName;
        }

        public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
            this.categoryName = categoryName;
        }

        public String getCategoryDescription() {
            return categoryDescription;
        }

        public void setCategoryDescription(String categoryDescription) {
            this.categoryDescription = categoryDescription;
        }

        public List<Product> getProducts() {
            return products;
        }

        public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
            this.products = products;
        }

    }
```

// ********************************************************
//My product DAO

which extends JPA Repository
 I am trying to write custom methods with the help of `@Query` Annotation

```
    package springmvc.java.dao;
    import springmvc.java.domain.Product;
    public interface ProductDAO extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {

        @Query("select p from Product p where p.categoryId = :categoryId")
        public List<Product> findProductsByCategoryId(@Param("categoryId") Long categoryId);`enter code here`
    }
```

// ********************************************************
//Stack Trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List springmvc.java.dao.ProductDAO.findProductsByCategoryId(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: categoryId of: springmvc.java.domain.Product [select p from springmvc.java.domain.Product p where p.categoryId = :categoryId]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1374)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: categoryId of: springmvc.java.domain.Product [select p from springmvc.java.domain.Product p where p.categoryId = :categoryId]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1968)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:494)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:598)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:881)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4426)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3898)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2076)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1778)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    ... 67 more
```

Answer (score 0):

`categoryId` - it's actually another entity in your relationship and you do need to access its `id` field.

`Query("select p from Product p where p.categoryId.id = :categoryId")
public List<Product> findProductsByCategoryId(@Param("categoryId") Long categoryId);`

Answer (score 0):

Correct query - select p from Product p where p.category = :categoryId"

Please note that, property name defined in Product entity is 'category' and not 'catagoryid'.
Hope correcting query above resolves exception.